# Streaming data OUT of Excel

Tags: excel, dde

I use a 3rd party application which writes data to Excel via DDE.  The values change every second, and it constantly overwrites whatever was there before.  But I'd like to have a constant log of what was there each second so I can analyse the history, so was hoping to stream the data to a file in real-time.

The Excel file is never saved so I writing (e.g.) some python or java code to read the Excel file wouldn't work.

Is there any means of exporting things OUT of Excel, such that it would automatically run every second (or even dynamically run whenever anything changed)?  Google is full of ways to stream live data INTO Excel, but not much on streaming data out in real-time.

Failing that, perhaps Excel itself has something clever where it can copy the data elsewhere in the worksheet so it preserves the history.